# Handling routing between nested pages

Tags: react-router

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path={`${path}/dashboard`} component={Dashboard} />
    <Route exact path={`${path}/submissions`} component={SubmissionSelect} />
    <Route exact path={`${path}/submissions/:id`} component={SubmissionPage} />
</Switch>
```

How it all works from the application (assuming that root url is `localhost:3000`):

- Clicking on the link to leads to `Dashboard` component, causes me to be routed to `localhost:3000/dashboard`
- Within the `Dashboard` component, I click on another link that brings me to the `SubmissionPage` component (e.g. `localhost:3000/submissions/9`)
- However, when I try to navigate back to the `Dashboard` component (or any other), the `URL` now becomes `localhost:3000/submissions/dashboard`
- As seen above the word `submissions` is wrongly appended to the end of the path and now the entire routing is broken.

I've tried to refer to the nested tutorial provided by `react-router-dom` below but it's a slightly different use-case.
https://reactrouter.com/web/example/nesting

Is there something wrong with my routing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try to implement my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start your routes with `/` which is relative to the root of your application. try this and also change your `Link component to use new addresses`:

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path={`/dashboard`} component={Dashboard} />
  <Route exact path={`/submissions`} component={SubmissionSelect} />
  <Route exact path={`/submissions/:id`} component={SubmissionPage} />
</Switch>;
```